# Images in iphone web app are hazy?

Tags: iphone, image, web-applications, safari

When I inserted some images into the web app,I found that the images were hazy.

I don't know how to make it looks more clear.

By the way the start page of the web app looks so hazy too.

Did you face this problem?

I hope that you can help me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not an expert on this - but can you give us a screenshot so we have a better idea of what you mean?

Comment: I had solve the problem and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had solve the problem by myself.i just use a larger picture to be the background and use CSS to set background-size make it suitable for the iPhone screen

Like this : 640*320 div

Your background images should be 640*320 and set the background size as 320*160